# Pass context to yield when using Meteor Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am starting to use [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) in my Meteor app and its `yields` for templating.
I've recently run into a problem where I can't start a named yield with a context, as follows:

```
{{#with context}}
    {{yield 'subtemplate'}}
{{/with}}
```

and get this error `Sorry, couldn't find a yield named "subtemplate". Did you define it in one of the rendered templates like this: {{yield "subtemplate"}}?`

If I remove the `{{#with}}` block expression, I am able to render the yield.

Does anyone know of a good way to pass the context to a named yield?

I have posted my problem as [an issue](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/357#issuecomment-31115834) on the `iron-router` github project, but haven't gotten any solution yet.

Would appreciate any help.

**EDIT 1/1/2014**: 
So my code looks like this:

```
// main template for the route
 <div class="form-container">
    <div class="form">
        {{yield 'section'}}
    </div>
</div>
```

The logic to get the yield section to display

```
// router.js
ApplyController = RouteController.extend({
    before: function() {
        var section = this.params.section || 'personal-info';
        Session.set('current', section);
    },
    action: function() {
        var section = Session.get('current');
        this.render();
        this.render(section, {
            to: 'section'
        });
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            app: Applications.findOne({user: Meteor.userId()})
        }
    }
});
```

Example of one of the section template:

```
<template name="education">
    {{#with app}}
    <form id="education" name="education" class="fragment" method="post" action="">
    <h2>Education</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="college" class="control-label">College/ University</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="college" name="college" placeholder="Select a College/ University">
                <option value="">Select a College/ University</option>
            {{#each colleges}}
                <option value="{{slug}}" {{selected slug ../college}}>{{name}}</option>
            {{/each}}
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- other content here -->
    </form>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Using the `{{#with app}}` block is how I currently get around this issue, but because I have 10 different section templates, I have to put that in all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You pass a data context in the router using ironrouter. You can't pass it this way because if you pass a route in the router it would override the route's data context.

It might however work with the shark branch of ironRouter which is based off Meteor UI since it uses `{{>yield}}` instead of `{{yield}}`.

You can use this though:

#### Route specific data context

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('template', data: function() { return Something.find() });
});
```

You basically pass the context using the `data` param. It might be easier to do it this way than to use `{{#with context}}` because you can use more dynamic data which is different for each route.

You might have tried this, I'm a bit unsure on whether it would go to a named yield's template.

#### Using an ordinary Template helper for the template

```
Template.templateInYieldName.helper = function() {
    return Something.find();
}
```

Then you can use something like `{{helper.name}}` in your named yield.

#### Global data context with handlebars helper

If you intend to use data for all the routes you can use a Handlebars global helper. i.e

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('todaysDate', function() {
    return (new Date).toString();
});
```

then just use `{{todaysDate}}` in any of your templates. You can use your data instead of a date instead.

Comment: I can definitely define the data context for the template, but what I want to achieve here is to define a data context for the named yield, which could be a few different subtemplates.

Comment: You could place the subtemplates in a single larger template which has the yield? is this not the same? Could you post the code you're using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry for the late update. I have put the code I'm using in the question above.